# Nombre del símbolo # en varios países

Tags: diferencias-regionales, nombres-propios, sustantivos

Varias veces, en publicidad radial o televisiva en Colombia, escucho que llaman a ese símbolo como *hashtag*. Yo lo conozco como *numeral*, pero estoy seguro que así no se le llama en otros países. ¿Qué nombres recibe el símbolo #?

Answer (score 4):

En España es *almohadilla*, pero no se suele usar mucho ya que ya existe la abreviatura/símbolo *N.º* (y sus variaciones *núm.* y *nro.*) con el mismo significado.  De hecho, la primera vez que aparece en una obra de la RAE es con el DPD aunque ese indica que se utiliza en las Américas como equivalente a *N.º*.  Ahora también sale en la edición más moderna del *Diccionario*, pero con una acepción exclusivamente relacionada con telecomunicaciones.  *Numeral* está definido como *almohadilla* con la indicación geográfica de la Argentina y el Uruguay.

Comment: ¿Cómo diría ud. en voz alta _#España_? ¿Número España? ¿Almohadilla España?

Comment: @David Ni idea, no lo uso :-)  Probablemente diría o *almohadilla* o *etiqueta* ya que en inglés suelo pronunciarlo según su función.  Según la página oficial de Twitter en español ( https://support.twitter.com/groups/53-discover/topics/216-trends/articles/247830-que-son-las-etiquetas-simbolos ) , parece ser «etiqueta» la forma de pronounciarlo.

Comment: # is not intended for spoken language. I would say "Hashtag España" if talking about Tweeter stuff, and "Almohadilla España" if dictating the spelling.

Comment: En instrucciones de sistemas automáticos telefónicos en España, la tecla se llama *almohadilla*. Por ejemplo, *para oír sus mensajes, pulse almohadilla*.

Comment: por lo menos en Cuba cuando se refiere al telefono, decimos `tecla número`, `tecla numeral` o `símbolo número`, cuando es referido a twiter o internet en general `Hashtag`

Comment: Cualquiera de los nombres en castellano es mejor que el original de los manuales de bell labs: ***octalthorpe*** es el horrible nombre original del símbolo con una etimología aproximada a *ocho espinas* que en efecto es el número de segmentos lineales o "espinas" que sobresalen del cuadrito central del mentado gato #

Answer (score 3):

En México se llama signo de número, o simplemente número y gato. El primer nombre se dice generalmente a la hora de poner números de casas y cosas por el estilo y gato cuando se usa para otras cosas como marcar números de teléfono y claro el novedoso hashtag que solo se usa para... hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

En España lo he oído nombrar también como "celdilla" o "cedilla" (esta última, más que probablemente, se trata de una pronunciación incorrecta de la anterior).