# ¿Por qué se le llama "almohadilla" al símbolo "#"?

Tags: historia, sustantivos

Siempre me ha resultado curioso el hecho de que al símbolo # se le diga "[almohadilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1zpdXXx)" (sí, soy de los que dicen que programan en "ce almohadilla", aunque tal vez debería decir "ce sostenido" o incluso "[do sostenido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp)").

> 14. f. *Telec.* Símbolo (#), parecido al sostenido, utilizado en telecomunicaciones.

Soy consciente de que en algunos países se le llama "numeral" también. El caso es que he estado buscando el por qué de ese nombre, y lo más que he encontrado es [su origen](http://www.eldiario.es/hojaderouter/shortcut/almohadilla-hashtag-numeral-historia-origen-twitter_6_355274480.html) (al parecer viene del Imperio Romano):

> Nace en la Antigua Roma, donde los latinos la llamaron ‘Libra pondo’ (peso en libras), abreviada como ‘lb’ y utilizada para esta antigua medida. Al acortarla, se solía poner una raya horizontal superior que cruzaba ambas letras. Con el tiempo, y al escribirla cada vez más rápido, el ‘lb’ se fue transformando.
>
> En el siglo XX, la almohadilla conoció un nuevo uso: formar parte de los teclados telefónicos. En 1968, los míticos laboratorios Bell decidieron añadir dos teclas a los lados del solitario cero; con ellas se podrían realizar más funciones. Eligieron el asterisco y la almohadilla  porque eran símbolos fáciles de reconocer por los ordenadores de la época y porque ya estaban en el teclado estándar QWERTY.

Entiendo pues que se le llame "numeral", al representar una cantidad numérica en libras, pero ¿y "almohadilla"? ¿Tanto se parece el símbolo # a un cojín? ¿Cuándo se le comenzó a llamar así?

Relacionada: [Nombre del símbolo # en varios países](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8760/12637)

Comment: Parece que por algo tan simple como que su forma `#` recuerda una almohada pequeña, también llamada [_almohadilla_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1zpdXXx) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQRX.jpg

Comment: @fedorqui a ver, yo imagino que algo así será, pero es que para mí el parecido no es tan obvio y quería confirmarlo. He añadido una pregunta más a ver si así la cuestión es más interesante. :-D

Comment: Solamente aclarar, como ya apunta la definición dentro de la pregunta ("Símbolo (#), parecido al sostenido"), que el símbolo de "sostenido" es "♯". Muy parecido, pero no es el mismo que el que nos atañe.

Comment: No se si la pregunta se merece el tag España. Por estos lados nunca lo hemos llamado Almohadilla sino Numero o Numeral....pero en el ámbito de programación no programamos en C-Numeral sino en C-Sharp

Answer (score 5):

Nótese la definición #12 del DRAE:

> **almohadilla**
>
> ...
>
> **12**. f. Arq. Parte del sillar que sobresale de la obra, con las aristas achaflanadas o redondeadas.

No entendí nada, pero en la Wikipedia pude aclarar el concepto en la entrada de [**Almohadillado**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almohadillado), de donde saqué éstas imágenes:

[image: almohadillado]
[image]

No sé si este es el origen de la acepción de la palabra, pero bien podría ser que la tipografía imita o se parece al almohadillado arquitectónico.

Nota: Queda entonces pendiente la duda de por qué se le dice *almohadilla* a este tipo de decoración de las paredes. Por lo que veo, como derivado de *almohada*, la palabra almohadilla se ha usado para referirse a cualquier tipo de abultamiento, al parecer por analogía con las almohadillas anatómicas, que son partes blandas, como almohadas pequeñas o cojines, que sobresalen del cuerpo y que tienen alguna función protectora. (P. ej. Las almohadillas de las patas de los gatos).